# Confused about the structure of it

Tags: sentence-construction

Here are few things to remember.
Is the above sentence correct?
I think the sentence should be : Here are few things to be remembered. 
Or, here are few things which are to be remembered.
Do the above sentences mean same?

Comment: I suspect you want "Here are **a** few things to remember".  Missing the article is not necessarily a grammatical mistake, but it changes the meaning somewhat.  "There are a few problems" is simply stating there are a small number / handful of problems.  "There are few problems" emphasises that there are few as opposed to many.

Comment: I am confused if it would be 'to remember' or 'to be remembered'. This is what I wanted to say.

Comment: "Here are a few things to remember" and "Here are a few things to be remembered" are both acceptable.  I have spent the last 5 minutes trying to think how to explain the difference between them, and failed.  I think they are essentially interchangeable, any difference in meaning is very subtle and subjective.  "Here are a few things which are to be remembered" is also grammatically fine, but seems excessively verbose; not so natural.  "Here are few things be remembered" is grammatically incorrect as it needs to be "to be".  Hope this helps.

Comment: Here the object of the verb 'remember' is 'few things'. So I think 'to be remembered' is more appropriate. Don't you?

Comment: The cited text *could* validly occur as a slightly stylised / literary  "reduced" form of *Here **there** are few things to remember* (where "here" refers to the *location* where there are few "mementos", not to the mementos themselves). Effectively *There aren't many things worth remembering about this place*.

Comment: But If I ask what to remember? Answer is ' few things'. So it should be 'to remembered'